# Edge contractions of a graph but only along maximum cliques

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Consider the following operation to an undirected graph: one is allowed to take any maximum clique and replace the clique with a single vertex which is attached to every single vertex which has an edge into the clique. Essentially then one is allowed to do a bunch of simultaneous edge contractions but only if they all form a maximum clique. One can then talk about what graphs can be formed from other graphs this way. Note if that a graph A can be formed from a graph B this way, then A is a minor of B, but the converse does not hold. One can think of this also as a restricted form of [quotient graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_graph) but only allowed to quotient out with subgraphs which are maximum cliques. Is there a term in the literature for this graph relation?

[I asked this question earlier on Math Stackexchange but did not get any answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4733879/edge-contractions-of-a-graph-but-only-along-maximum-cliques).